# Do I need embedding in LSTM if I have double datatype as input (DataType: double)

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I want to implement LSTM. 
input_size: 10x512x7x7 (DataType: double)
output_size: 512x7x7 (DataType: double)

Do I need embedding layer, I heard embedding is used to convert word_to_number…
Could you explain more about the embedding layer in LSTM…?

Comment: Is the 7x7 feature set spatial, like an image, or do you have 7x7=49 independent features at each time step?

Comment: That 512x7x7 is output from Encoder part (like SegNet).  I have 10 input images so I got 10 times 512x7x7 "feature" from Encoder part.

Comment: I see. Then I think you can just Flatten() and TimeDistributed() to make your data shaped as 10x512x49 and pass to LSTM layers.